# How can I convert List<dynamic> to excel file type in Flutter to downlad file locally and store in device

Tags: excel, flutter, download

I need to download excel file to device, the api return is List, the sample data is shown below.

```
{"data":[{"First Name":"1","Last Name":"Dulce","Gender":"Abril","Country":"Female","Age":"United States","Date":"32","Id":"15/10/2017"},{"First Name":"2","Last Name":"Mara","Gender":"Hashimoto","Country":"Female","Age":"Great Britain","Date":"25","Id":"16/08/2016"},{"First Name":"3","Last Name":"Philip","Gender":"Gent","Country":"Male","Age":"France","Date":"36","Id":"21/05/2015"},{"First Name":"4","Last Name":"Kathleen","Gender":"Hanner","Country":"Female","Age":"United States","Date":"25","Id":"15/10/2017"},{"First Name":"5","Last Name":"Nereida","Gender":"Magwood","Country":"Female","Age":"United States","Date":"58","Id":"16/08/2016"}]}
```

My question is how can i make excel file from this array. I have to create excel file and download it to phone (device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package [excel](https://pub.dev/packages/excel)

```
import 'package:excel/excel.dart';


class ExcelReportExtractor {
  final Excel excelFile = Excel.createExcel();
  create({required Map<String, dynamic> model}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> merged = {};
    merged.addEntries([MapEntry("Created at:", DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm').format(DateTime.now().toUtc()))]);
    merged.addEntries(model.entries);

    Sheet defaultSheet = excelFile[excelFile.getDefaultSheet()!];
    List.generate(merged.keys.length, (index) {
      if (index % 2 == 0) {
        defaultSheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByString(
          "A${(index + 1).toString()}",
        ))
          ..value = formatString(merged.keys.elementAt(index));

        defaultSheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByString(
          "B${(index + 1).toString()}",
        ))
          ..value = merged.values.elementAt(index)
          ..cellStyle = CellStyle(
            bold: true,
            textWrapping: TextWrapping.WrapText,
            fontFamily: getFontFamily(FontFamily.Arial),
            rotation: 0,
            horizontalAlign: HorizontalAlign.Right,
          );
      } else {
        defaultSheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByString(
          "A${(index + 1).toString()}",
        ))
          ..value = formatString(merged.keys.elementAt(index))
          ..cellStyle = CellStyle(backgroundColorHex: '#D7D7D7');

        defaultSheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByString(
          "B${(index + 1).toString()}",
        ))
          ..value = merged.values.elementAt(index)
          ..cellStyle = CellStyle(
              bold: true, textWrapping: TextWrapping.WrapText, fontFamily: getFontFamily(FontFamily.Arial), rotation: 0, horizontalAlign: HorizontalAlign.Right, backgroundColorHex: '#D7D7D7');
      }
    });

    defaultSheet.setColAutoFit(0);
    defaultSheet.setColAutoFit(1);

    excelFile.save(fileName: "output.xlsx");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSV data can be generated without any extra dependencies, assuming it fulfils the requirements. Something like this:

```
final data = jsonDecode(json)["data"];
final buffer = StringBuffer()
  ..writeAll(data[0].keys, ",")
  ..writeln();
for (final item in data) {
  buffer
    ..writeAll(item.values, ",")
    ..writeln();
}
```

Comment: I don't know how does it work with StringBuffer()?